# Getting JavaScript error on asynchronous postback scope function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the following error reported on angular.min.js

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Error' is undefined

with the following code:

Javascipt:

```
function Sucess() 
{
    //close
}

function Save() 
{
    var e = document.getElementById('FormDiv');
    scope = angular.element(e).scope();
    scope.Apply(Sucess)
}
```

My Angular scope function:

```
function RolesCtrl($scope, $http, $location) 
{
    $scope.Apply = function (CallBackSucess) {

    var userId = getQSP('uid', decode(document.URL));
    $http({
    method: 'POST', url: 'MultiRole.aspx/Apply',
    data: {}
    }).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        CallBackSucess();
        $scope.f = data.d;
        }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
    $scope.name = 'error';
    })
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be working fine until `CallBackSucess()` call is made which throws the error:

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Error' is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CallBackSucess` argument is passed to the `.Apply()` method.  It is not passed to the `.success()` method - they are chained methods with separate scopes.    Thus, in the `.success()` callback function, `CallbackSucess()` is not defined when you try to call it and thus you get an error.

Also, do you really mean to spell `Sucess` incorrectly?

FYI, I had to format your code like this in order to see what was actually going on:

```
function RolesCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.Apply = function (CallBackSucess) {
        var userId = getQSP('uid', decode(document.URL));
        $http({
            method: 'POST', 
            url: 'MultiRole.aspx/Apply',
            data: {}
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            CallBackSucess();
            $scope.f = data.d;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            $scope.name = 'error';
        })
    }
}
```